# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'str'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

In my following code I am trying to append  to every start and end of the value so that I can perform SQL insert operation directly after running my python script.

Following is code

```
print today,","+ (a['href'] if a else '`NULL`')+",", (a.string if a else 'NULL, NULL')+ "," +",".join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", (a['onclick'] if a else 'NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL')))+","+ ", ".join([project] + area),","+pdates+""
```

Here is my whole [code](https://github.com/Venkateshwaran/ScreenScraping/blob/2e149c0b7fb693fc60abef40b39bc3cdc0693333/velachery.py)

And the [output](https://github.com/Venkateshwaran/ScreenScraping/blob/2e149c0b7fb693fc60abef40b39bc3cdc0693333/final.sql) I am getting . Hope I am clear about what I want.

Comment: This would be a whole lot clearer if you used `{}`-formatting or `%`-formatting instead of string concatenation and `print` magic commas. (For one thing, formatting will automatically stringify its arguments, while `+` will not.) Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/SxGXGZJ2).

Comment: Also, which code is the one you're using? The one posted here or the one in your gist? Can you update either to reflect the correct version?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're doing the `+""` at the end. That's effectively pointless in Python, and it implies that you're expecting some more weakly-typed language like Javascript or PHP that will automatically stringify anything added to a string.

Comment: Finally, trying to build a SQL statement out of pieces like this is always a bad idea. You get [SQL injection problems](http://xkcd.com/327/), quoting/escaping bugs, bad performance, and complicated and hard-to-debug code. It's far better to use placeholders, as [the top section of the `sqlite3` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) explains.

Comment: I wish I could understand what you people are saying. But sadly my experience with python itself is not more than 5 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
(a['href'] if a + '1' else '`NULL`')
```

`a` is an instance of a `Tag` class, `1` is a string.

I guess you need just an `if a` check:

```
(a['href'] if a else '`NULL`')
```

And, FYI, better use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) or [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) instead of concatenating strings manually using `+`.

And, even better to use parameterized sql statements (see [sqlite3 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)):

```
query = """
INSERT INTO
    `property`
    (`date`,`Url`,`Rooms`,`place`,`PId`,`Phonenumber1`,`Phonenumber2`,`Phonenumber3`,`Typeofperson`,` Nameofperson`,`typeofproperty`,`Sq.Ft`,`PerSq.Ft`,`AdDate`,`AdYear`)
VALUES
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
"""

# define your field values as a list
values = [today, a['href'] if a else 'NULL', ... ]

# execute
cursor.execute(query, values)
```

Comment: Yes. I knew the problem. Sorry that I dint push the right code to git. But I need to add ` ` to every value in .sql file which I have mentioned as output

Comment: Arg! I was literally halfway down on the enter key!

Comment: @PhillipCloud yeah, that's what I usually say when Martijn is answering :)

Comment: @alecxe Yes My actual code is here, which does not have any error.
[link](https://github.com/Venkateshwaran/ScreenScraping/blob/f2be4217c72a247cb8329d52dd22cd649c008cc7/velachery.py)

Comment: @Venky I've made a hint in the answer on how you should make a query, please check and try to finish it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks alecxe. I would do it

Answer (score 1):

Turn this:

```
print today,","+ (a['href'] if a else '`NULL`')+",", (a.string if a else 'NULL, NULL')+ "," +",".join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", (a['onclick'] if a else 'NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL')))+","+ ", ".join([project] + area),","+pdates+""
```

into this:

```
# create your format string
keys = 'date', 'url', 'rooms',  # etc...
fmt_s = ', '.join('{{{key}}}'.format(key=key) for key in keys)
# yields: '{date}, {url}, ...'

# build up the necessary values
params = {'date': today}
params['url'] = a['href'] if a else '`NULL`'
params['rooms'] = a.string if a else 'NULL, NULL'

# etc...

# first format fills in the values from the dict
# second format adds the parens
print("({0})".format(fmt_s.format(**params)))
```

Can you finish up the rest?

It's still better to use parameterized SQL, than to build up your string manually.